# MySQL - add leading underscore on reserved keywords for columns?

Tags: mysql, backticks

Is it safe to add **leading** underscores on reserved keywords for **columns**?

For instance: `_key`

There too many reserved keywords and it is hard to avoid.

For instance currently I am using `code` to replace `key` to avoid collision.

But what happens if one day they decide to add `code` into the reserved keywords? Then I have to find new keyword again or adding **backticks** - which is a lot do to maintain!

Comment: IMO `_key` is way more error prone than just using backticks. What is the content of your column?

Comment: `What is the content of your column?` for instance: `group_name_1` it can be `longtext` or `char` or `int`.

Comment: @juergend why `_key is way more error prone`?

Comment: I would forget the underscore a lot.

Comment: Isn't it then more a `name` instead of a `key`?

Comment: `more than a name` - what do u mean?

Comment: I mean wouldn't `id` or `name` be a better name for the column?

Comment: i have id and name in the table already. need key/ code in it that's all.

Comment: Side note: don't forget that not all keywords are *reserved* keywords.

Answer (score 1):

There are tens or hundreds of thousands of words in the English language. There are a few hundred reserved words in SQL. It should not be hard to avoid the reserved words, particularly because you should strive for *descriptive* column names rather than *short* column names.

So, if you have something in your business that you call a `key`, is it a key for a customer (`CustomerKey`)? For a location (`LocationKey`)?  For a door (`DoorKey`)?  You get the idea.

In addition, I normally follow these naming conventions:

- Tables are names in the plural (few keywords are plural, although one is `values`).
- The id for the table is the singular of the table name followed by `id` or `_id`.
- Foreign key references -- where possible -- have the name of the primary key of the table they are referring to.

Comment: Where does this naming conventions come from?

Comment: `Tables are names in the plural (few keywords are plural, although one is values)` not sure about this. have looked around and some suggest using singular as convention...

Comment: @teelou . . . In my books, I recommend plurals for the names of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using a leading `_` character currently has no conflicts with MySQL's [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), but in theory they could start using that character in the future. The chances of it are quite low, but that's not a strict guarantee.

It's true that each new version of MySQL may introduce a few new keywords. If you want to prepare for any new reserved keywords, the only sure solution is to develop a habit of using back-ticks on *all* your identifiers.

The same risk exists in any other programming language, by the way. This is inconvenient for anyone using those words as names of functions, classes, or constants.

- PHP 7.1 introduced reserved words `void` and `iterable`, and `object` was added in PHP 7.2.
- Java 4 added `assert`, Java 5 added `enum`, and Java 9 added `_` as reserved words.
- JavaScript/ECMAScript has a complex history of adding *and removing* reserved words. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords
- Python 3 added reserved words `False`, `True`, `None`, `__peg_parser__`, `async`, `await`, `nonlocal`, and removed as keywords `exec` and `print`.

Ultimately, you just need to accept that when you upgrade a major version of some software, you have to do some work to accommodate its changes.